# what is the maximum possible height of an AVL tree with n nodes

Tags: c

Is there any way to find the maximum height of an AVL tree with n nodes.We know the upper bound of height of an AVL tree which is approximately 1.44*logn.If we have 7 nodes the maximum possible height is 3 not 4(1.44*log7).

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that in `1.44*log(n)` that's log *base 2*... so that's ~`2.08*ln(n)`, which for 7 is ~4.0475.

I have seen, variously:

```
  1.4404 * log2(n + 2) - 0.328

  1.44   * log2(n + 1) − 0.3
```

but all in terms of log2().